# How to replace an element from the another same vector, but the another vector will not be changed?

Tags: python

Here I have a vector `a=[1,2,3,4,5]`

```
a=b
a[0]=a[2]
print a
a=[2,2,3,4,5]
b=[2,2,3,4,5]
```

but I don't want vector b to be changed, I want it always `b=[1,2,3,4,5]`

Actually, you can regard b as the original vector of a.

Comment: `a = b` does not copy the data from `b` to a new location in `a`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use copy funtion like this :

```
    a=b.copy()
    a[0]=a[2]
    print a
    a=[3,2,3,4,5]
    b=[2,2,3,4,5]
```

for a list, a = b just copies the reference. So when you change one value of the list then the value of all variables (those hold the same reference) become changed. `copy()` or `deepcopy()` function actually copies the list. You can read [this doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html3).

Update with your input :

```
b=[1,2,3,4,5]
a=b.copy()
a[0]=a[2]
print(a)
print(b)
```

It prints :

```
[3, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Using list slicing in this case is weird but working one :

```
b=[1,2,3,4,5]
a=b[:]
a[0]=a[2]
print(a)
print(b)
```

Comment: But the vector b is changed...
I hope it can always be b=[1,2,3,4,5]

Comment: Sorry, it works. You are right! I just made some ridiculous mistakes

Comment: Please read my updated comment. I have updated it with your input. Is this answer acceptable now?

Comment: Yes, you solve my problem. And thanks for the document you posted. ^_^